# Logging into Facebook takes longer than usual

Tags: firefox

When I want to log in to Facebook using Firefox it takes a long time to upload and I see this message at the bottom left corner of my screen: *Tranferring data from fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net*. It never used to do that, why is this happening?

Comment: does it do that with Chrome (or other browser) as well?

Comment: It is possible you have a corrupt image in your Facebook account.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds an awful lot like a cache/cookie problem. Try clearing out your browser's cache and cookies.

I've had issues similar to this before too, clearing out the cookies and cache have always fixed them right away.